# In webView leads to crash and UI unresponsiveness

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview, wkwebview

I have added a WebView to load HTML and the baseUrl method. But it leads to crashing the app and showing a warning

> This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to
> UI unresponsiveness.

```
//load HTML
let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")
let folderPath = Bundle.main.bundlePath
let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: folderPath, isDirectory: true)
do {
    let htmlString = try NSString(contentsOfFile: htmlPath!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    self.webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString as String, baseURL: URL(string: newBaseURL))
} catch {
    // catch error
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

I have called this piece of code in viewDidLoad(). Also it has been added in dispatch queue. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I hope self.webView is WKWebView also what is the error you are getting in XCode logs? is the index.html file present inside your bundle?

Comment: @Satheesh it present and loading the iframe but when loading large data it leads to crash

Comment: crash logs, please?

Comment: @Satheesh Now it not showing the crash but it leads to ui unresponsiveness and disconnecting the iphone. not able to even debug..

Comment: Why don't you use the `bundleURL` variable you created? What is the `newBaseURL` variable that is being used in the code but not shown? Why do you create `bundleURL` from `folderPath` ? Why not directly use `Bundle.main.bundleURL` ?

Answer (score 1):

Call `loadHTMLString` from the main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString as String, baseURL: URL(string: newBaseURL))

}
```

Comment: Tried this already but still facing same issue

Comment: Yes need more info.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues and one of them is a bug address by Apple itself -

a. Warning of WKWebkit on main thread - This has been covered by one of Apple's engineers where he goes into detail on [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714467?answerId=734799022#734799022) thread. Short answer - Its a bug and Apple is working on it in further releases. Now according to them this is supposed to be a warning and it shouldnt have any issues with the API itself.

b. The Webview is unresponsive. As explained above the warning shouldn't be causing an issue with anything API related. So for this I would suggest you to check the HTML you are trying to render separately. If that works fine, maybe try to launch it in a separate device, or even simulator. Try to make the HTML render on a consistent basis in other environment(device / simulator). I think either the device you are using has an older OS.

Please try to test the same HTML on separate devices / simulators and share your results here.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you can move the code that loads the HTML string and sets the baseURL to a background thread using DispatchQueue. This will allow the main thread to continue running and handling user input, preventing the app from becoming unresponsive. Checkout the below code:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")
    let folderPath = Bundle.main.bundlePath
    let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: folderPath, isDirectory: true)
    do {
        let htmlString = try NSString(contentsOfFile: htmlPath!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString as String, baseURL: URL(string: newBaseURL))
        }
    } catch {
        // catch error
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```